# How do you measure the differential gain in an instrumentation amplfier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

How can I measure the differential gain Ad from the formula s = Ad(e1-e2) in the following circuit?

[image]

Comment: How far have you gotten and where are you stuck? By the way, we'd generally call this a "differential amplifier", not an "instrumentation amplifier". The latter typically has two high-impedance inputs.

Comment: i built this circuit in proteus isis but i don't know the method for calculating Ad, @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Connect a 1mV sin wave between e1 and e2. Now plot the output in mV as well. Divide to get the gain. I don't know your resistor values, but you can experiment with amplitude.